# Using regexes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex, that I'm trying to use in Ruby. Here is my Regex, and it works in Java when I add the double escape keys

```
\(\*(.*?)\*\)
```

I know this is a simple question, but how would I write this as a ruby expression and set it equal to a variable? I appreciate any help.

Comment: It'd help us check for correctness, if you'd supply some samples of what you expect it to match, and not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
myregex = /\(\*(.*?)\*\)/
```

To be clear, this is just to save the regex to a variable. To use it:

```
"(**)" =~ myregex
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if /\(\*(.*?)\*\)/ === "(*hello*)"
  content = $1 # => "hello"
end
```

http://rubular.com/r/7eCuPX3ri0

Comment: I think you mean =~ rather than ==

Comment: Ah, it is `===` or `=~` indeed

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are a native type in Ruby (the actual class is "Pattern"). You can just write:

```
mypat = /\(\*(.*?)\*\)/
```

[Looks like anything between '(*' / '*)' pairs, yes?]

You can then do

```
m = mypat.match(str)
comment = m[1]
```

...or, more compactly

```
comment = mypat.match(str)[1]
```

Comment: The actual class, in MRI 1.8 and 1.9, is `Regexp`.